# Jenkins deployment into Weblogic 12c FAILING

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to deploy the war file from Jenkins to Weblogic 12 server and it's failing with the below error message.

```
CAN ANY ONE PLEASE COMMENT ON THE BELOW Jenkins console ERROR, NOT SURE WHAT I AM MISSING

$ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin/java" -Xms512M -Xmx512M -cp C:\SOFTWA~1\WLS121~1\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer -debug -remote -verbose -noexit -name trucks -targets AdminServer -adminurl t3://wsxxxx:7001 -user Admin -password pa$$w0rd -undeploy
[WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - ARTIFACT UNDEPLOYED SUCCESSFULLY.
[WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - DEPLOYING ARTIFACT...
$ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin/java" -Xms512M -Xmx512M -cp C:\SOFTWA~1\WLS121~1\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer -debug -stage -remote -verbose -upload -name trucks -source C:\Users\aa\.jenkins\workspace\mytruck\target\trucks.war -targets AdminServer -adminurl t3://wsxxxx:7001 -user Admin -password pa$$w0rd -deploy
java.lang.RuntimeException: task completed abnormally (exit code = 1)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.deploy.weblogic.task.DeploymentTaskServiceImpl.deploy(DeploymentTaskServiceImpl.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.deploy.weblogic.task.DeploymentTaskServiceImpl.perform(DeploymentTaskServiceImpl.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.deploy.weblogic.WeblogicDeploymentPlugin.perform(WeblogicDeploymentPlugin.java:236)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
ERROR: [WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - Failed to deploy.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] DEPLOYMENT FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build step 'Deploy the artifact to any Weblogic environments' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Jenkins is able to generate the artifact (war file) but when it tries to deploy onto weblogic 12c it failing, but i am able to login with the same credentials into the weblogic console.

Comment: [b]Also The "Weblogic deployments logs" @ Jenkins says like below[/b]
[ServerConnectionImpl.close():361] : Unregistered all listeners
weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 't3://wsxxxx:7001': User: Admin, failed to be authenticated.. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.
 at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.connect(Jsr88Operation.java:317)
 at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.perform(Deployer.java:137)

Comment: Caused by: javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.DeploymentManagerCreationException: User: Admin, failed to be authenticated.
 at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:137)
 at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.factories.internal.DeploymentFactoryImpl.getDeploymentManager(DeploymentFactoryImpl.java:86)
 at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.getRemoteDeploymentManager(SessionHelper.java:530)
 at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.connect(Jsr88Operation.java:298)
 ... 6 more

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME TO GET AROUND THIS ISSUE. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use the authMode of BY_LOGIN and set the login and password in the  tags of your WebLogic Deployer configuration file.

```
<login>weblogic</login>
<password>password</password>
<authMode>BY_LOGIN</authMode>
```

Comment: This is my xml file content....
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://org.jenkinsci.plugins/WeblogicDeploymentPlugin"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://org.jenkinsci.plugins/WeblogicDeploymentPlugin plugin-configuration.xsd"> 
<weblogic-targets>
 <weblogic-target>
  <name>WeblogicDeploymentPlugin</name>
  <host>wsxxxx</host>
  <port>7001</port>
  <login>Admin</login>
  <password>pa$$w0rd</password>
  <authMode>BY_LOGIN</authMode>
 </weblogic-target>
</weblogic-targets>
</config>

Comment: But still i am getting the error...Please let me know what am I missing

Comment: Can you use that username and password to login to the console? Do you see any errors in the WebLogic logs?